# teradata case when issue

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following queries which are supposed to give the same result, but drastically different
1.

```
         select count(*)
         from qigq_sess_parse_2
         where str_vendor = 'natural search' and str_category is null and destntn_url = 'http://XXXX.com';
```

2. ```
        create table qigq_test1 as
        (
          select case
               when (str_vendor = 'natural search' and str_category is null and destntn_url = 'http://XXXX.com' ) then 1
               else 0 
           end as m
           from qigq_sess_parse_2
         ) with data;  

        select count(*)  from qigq_test1 where m = 1;
   ```

the first block gives a total number of count 132868, while the second one only gives 1.

What are the subtle parts in the query that causes this difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you create a table in Teradata, you can specify it to be `SET` or `MULTISET`.  If you don't specify, it defaults to `SET`.  A set table cannot contain duplicates.  So at most, your new table will contain two rows, a 0 and a 1, since that's all that can come from your case statement.

EDIT:
After a bit more digging, the defaults aren't quite that simple.  But in any case, I suspect that if you add the MULTISET option to your create statement, you'll see the behavior your expect.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually made a mistake of mistaking a tab for a space in the 'natural search' string, which I did not find in the Teradata SQL. But I appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your `Create Table` statement is only pulling in one row of data that fits the parameters for the following `Count` statement. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE qigq_test1 (m integer);
INSERT INTO qigq_test1
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (str_vendor = 'natural search' and str_category IS NULL AND destntn_url = 'http://XXXX.com' ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END AS m
FROM qigq_sess_parse_2;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qigq_test1 WHERE m = 1;
```

This should pull **ALL ROWS** of data from `qigq_sess_parse_2` into `qigq_test1` as either a 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually made a mistake of mistaking a tab for a space in the 'natural search' string, which I did not find in the Teradata SQL. But I appreciate your advice!